# Computing the chromatic polynomial of graph modulo $x-3$

Tags: graph-theory, polynomials, algorithms, computational-complexity, graph-colorings

The chromatic polynomial of graph $P(G,x)$ is univariate
polynomial which counts the number of colorings of $G$
with $x$ colors for natural $x$.

Graph is not $k$ colorable iff $P(G,k)=0$.

The chromatic polynomial of clique $K_n$ is
$x(x-1)(x-2)\ldots(x-(n-1))$

A graph is 3-colorable iff
$P(G,x) \not \equiv 0 \pmod{x-3}$ (in other
words 3 is not a root of $P(G,x)$.

The goal is to check 3-colorability by
computing $P(G,x) \pmod{x-3}$.

For non adjacent vertices $u$ and $v$, $G+uv$ 
is the graph with the edge $uv$ added and
the graph $G/uv$ is obtained by merging the two vertices.

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial)

$$P(G,k)= P(G+uv, k) + P(G/uv,k) \qquad (1) $$

And the terminating conditions are cliques.

So $G$ is not 3-colorable iff all terminal cliques are on
more than $3$ vertices.

When computing (1) $\mod x-3$, we have the following
terminal conditions.

(A) if $F$ contains $K_4$ as (induced) subgraph it
is not 3-colorable and we return $P(F,k) \equiv 0 \pmod{x-3}$ without
bothering to compute later.

(B) if $F$ is clique on 3 or less vertices, $G$
is 3-colorable since this a terminating clique.

Adding edges and merging vertices tends to induce $K_4$
and (A) is often hit, which makes computing $P(G,x) \pmod{x-3}$
strictly faster than the full $P(G,x)$ and this decides
3-colorability.

Consider the following naive algorithm for checking
3-colorability using $P(G,x) \pmod{x-3}$.

```
 function color3(G: connected graph)
 #returns 0 if G is not 3-colorable, otherwise reports it is and stops
 if G contains induced K_4 
     return 0
 if G is a clique on 3 or less vertices 
     report '3-colorable'. Stop.
 if we can add edge uv which induces K_4 in G 
     return color3(G/uv) #the induced K_4 contributes 0 to the sum
 #the above makes the problem strictly smaller
 #this might be greatly improved by trying to induce K_4-e
 [C] pick the lexicographic first non-adjacent u,v and return color3(G+uv)+color3(G/uv)
```

One call to color3 is polynomial, so the complexity
depends on the number of double recursion in [C].

According to Wikipedia the worst case for computing (1)
is $\phi^{n+m}$. 3-coloring 4-regular graphs is NP-complete,
so for 4-regular it is $\phi^{3n}$.

Appears to me terminating by induced $K_4$ would greatly
improve the running time.

Questions:

> Q1 What is the complexity of color3?

$O(c^n)$ for small $c$ will be of practical interest.
$2^{o(n)}$ might indicate complexity collapse.

> Q2 How to improve [C]?

There might be other improvements like other 4-chromatic
subgraph or $F$ being in a graph class where coloring is polynomial.

Experimental results:

For several 4-regular graphs on 246 vertices which are the line
graphs of 3-regular graphs color3 found 3-coloring in less than
a minute in sage 6.2 implementation. For several smaller
graphs which are not 3-colorable it correctly returned 0.
For reduction SAT to 3-color the running time was fast too.

**Added** Choosing the lexicographically first edge
appears good choice. It adds high degree vertices
and is experimentally much faster than choosing 
a random edge. (Another good choice is too add
edge between the two highest degree vertices).

> Q3 How to explain the fast experimental
>   results, including 4-chromatic graph on 75 vertices
>   and the reductions from SAT?

Sage implementation:  https://gist.github.com/jor0/039127ab69dd8934c105

> Q4 For 4-regular graph on 50 vertices, what is the current
>   record for maximum number of steps of the above implementation?

Comment: Very related question on cstheory: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/25299/complexity-of-an-algorithm-for-deciding-3-colorability-of-graph-by-the-chromatic

Comment: Recursion to instances smaller by an additive constant is the standard technique for beating the obvious brute-force search algorithm for a wide variety of NP-hard problems. It normally leads to runtimes of the form $c^n$. Are you familiar with state-of-the-art 3-colouring algorithms such as  http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020019010003595 , https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/pubs/Epp-SODA-01.pdf ?

Comment: Errr, I missed that one sorry.

Comment: @Jernej What is the fastest way say in Boost to find induced diamonds (K_4 minus edge)?

Comment: @Joro, Btw, a way to speed up such recursion is to cache graphs, see how this is done for the chromatic polynomial to gain an extreme speedup http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/14529 Though this introduces the isomorphism problem and breaks complexity analysis.

Comment: @Jernej Thanks. I don't want isomorphism. The current sage implementation does 300 vertices 4 regular in about minute. Appears to me hardest are 4-chromatic, though they seem polynomial to me too.

Comment: @Jernej I mean the number of calls in the recursion appear polynomial to me. Exponential in 300 will take long. Exponential in 4-regular 4-chromatic order 75 too, though in practice this is fast. Did you notice the link to sage code?

Comment: @Joro. Question - given that you work with 4-regular graphs, isn't it faster to use the edge deleting recursion? I am not sure you can say anything about the time complexity from the execution on instances of a concrete size since run time may as well be a function that "behaves" as a polynomial up to a certain fixed threshold .

Comment: @Jernej I don't think the deletion will work. It terminates in trees, not in cliques. Trees are 2-colorable and don't see how to terminate early. Do you see such way?